# What is the number of distinct homomorphism from $\Bbb Z/5 \Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z/7 \Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

> What is the number of distinct homomorphism from $\Bbb Z/5 \Bbb Z$  to  $\Bbb Z/7 \Bbb Z$ and how to find it?

I came across the above problem and do not know how to get it? Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: A homomorphism $\phi : {\mathbb Z}_5 \to {\mathbb Z}_7$ is completely deteremined by $\phi(1)$. Now what values can $\phi(1)$ take ?

Comment: How does $\phi (1)$ come into picture? Can you explain a bit?

Comment: learner: Take $\phi$ to be any homomorphism. $1$ is the (a) generator of $\mathbb Z_5$.  Any homomorphism is completely determined by the value to which it maps a generator.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks a lot ,sir.Got it. Then the answer should be $\phi (1)=1.$ Am I right?

Comment: @learner: No, it can't be $\phi(1)$, because if $\phi(1) = 1$, $\phi\left(\Bbb{Z}_5\right) = \{0,1,2,3,4\}\subseteq\Bbb{Z}_7$, which is not a subgroup.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy and learner: I think you're speaking past each other. It seems like Ewan thinks you're talking about $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ as rings and thus that the question is about ring homomorphisms. And for a ring homomorphism $\varphi: R \to S$ it is indeed (usually) required that $\varphi(1_R) = 1_S$.

Comment: @learner I'd strongly suggest you to write $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ instead of $\mathbb Z_p$ because the latter could be interpreted by some as the $p$-adic integers.

Comment: @kahen I don't think Ewan is talking about ring homomorphisms, as his comment is simply a statement that if we have a homomorphism $\phi$ from a cyclic group $G$ to another group, the homomorphism is completely determined by $\phi(g)$, where $g$ is a generator of $G$. Also, I don't think there's too much of a confusion with $\Bbb{Z}_p$, as the question is tagged with "cyclic groups" and "finite groups."

Comment: @kahen I have edited my post to eliminate confusion regarding it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint 1 (looking at subgroups and their orders):** Any homomorphism $\Bbb{Z}_5\xrightarrow{\phi}\Bbb{Z}_7$ yields a subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_7$ given by $\phi\left(\Bbb{Z}_5\right)$. What are the subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}_7$? Given the subgroups and their orders, what possibilites are there for $\phi\left(\Bbb{Z}_5\right)$? (You might want to use [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29).)

**Hint 2 (following the hint in the comment):** Both groups are cyclic and generated by $1$. Therefore, a homomorphism $\phi : \Bbb{Z}_5\to\Bbb{Z}_7$ is determined by where $1$ is sent (since any element $k\in\Bbb{Z}_5$ is equal to $k\cdot 1 = \underbrace{1 + \ldots + 1}_{k\textrm{ times}}$). So $\phi(1)$ generates a subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_7$. Think about the possibilities for the size of the subgroup given by $\left<\phi(1)\right>\subseteq\Bbb{Z}_7$ based on the orders of $\Bbb{Z}_5$ and $\Bbb{Z}_7$ (and hence the possibilities for $\phi(1)$).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. The problem is actually a multiple choice question and the possible answers were $0,1,5,7.$From the explanation it seems that $5$ is the correct choice.

Comment: What is your reasoning to say that $5$ is the right choice?

Comment: Since " the possibilities for the size of the subgroup given by $\left<\phi(1)\right>\subseteq\Bbb{Z}_7$ based on the orders of $\Bbb{Z}_5$ and $\Bbb{Z}_7$ " and the order of $\Bbb Z_5$ being $5$. Am I missing something,sir?

Comment: You should look at the possibilities of sizes of subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}_7$ (use Lagrange's theorem)

Answer (score 5):

The first homomorphism gives that if $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}_5 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_7$ is a homomorphism, then $\mathbb{Z}_5/\operatorname{ker}\varphi\cong \varphi[\mathbb{Z}_5]$.  Since the only subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ are the trivial subgroup and $\mathbb{Z}_5$ itself, the image of $\varphi$ must either be trivial or isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$.  No subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ can be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$ by Lagrange's theorem, so $\varphi$ must be the trivial homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $\,G,H\,$ are groups and $\,f:G\to H\,$ a group homomorphism, then

$$(1)\;\;\;\forall\,g\in G\;,\;\;ord(f(g))\mid ord(g)$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\text{Both groups given are cyclic of (co)prime order}\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the other answers have trouble getting to the point.   The only subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ are the trivial group and the entire group since $7$ is prime. Since $\phi(\mathbb{Z}_5) \le \mathbb{Z}_7$ is a subgroup, it must have either $1$ or $7$ elements.  It can't possibly have $7$ since $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a group of order $5$.  So $\phi(\mathbb{Z}_5) = \{0\} \implies$ $\phi$ is trivial.

Comment: Some of the answers only give hints so that the OP can take a look and get a push in the right direction, not just have the answer explicitly given to him.

Comment: @user70300 Got your point. Thanks for the explanation.+1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Let group hom $\rm\:f\,:\,\Bbb Z_5\to \Bbb Z_7\:$ with kernel $\rm\,K,\,$ and image $\rm\,I\,$ of size $\rm\:\#I = n$.

Note $\rm\ n\mid 7\ $ by Lagrange: $\rm\ I\,$ is a subgroup of $\rm\,\Bbb Z_7\:\Rightarrow\: \#I \mid \#\Bbb Z_7,\ $ i.e. $\rm\ n\mid 7$.

Note $\rm\ n\mid 5\ $ by $\rm\ I \cong \Bbb Z_5/K\:\Rightarrow\: \#I\, =\, \#\Bbb Z_5/\#K,\ $ i.e. $\rm\ n = 5/\#K$

Thus $\rm\:n\mid 5,7\:\Rightarrow\:n\mid gcd(5,7)=1,\ $ i.e. $\rm\ \#I = n = 1,\:$ so the image $\rm\,I\,$ is trivial.

Comment: What is #$ I$? Is it indicating the size of I?

Comment: @learner Yes, size, i.e. cardinality, as in the first sentence "size #I = n"